# Beautiful Soup - Why does my scrape stop half way through table?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to figure out why my web scrape stops half way through?

My code:

```
import requests,re
from  bs4  import  BeautifulSoup

url ="http://odds.aussportsbetting.com/betting?competitionid=15"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html')

#get market
m_data = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'tabContent'})
for items in m_data:
     all_rows = items.findAll('tr')

     for data in all_rows:
          game = data.findAll('a', {'title': 'Click To Compare Odds'})
          market = data.findAll('a', {'title': 'Click To Compare Odds Sorted By Best Bookmaker Odds'})

          for g_row in game:             
               text = ''.join(g_row.findAll(text=True))
               g_data = text.strip()

               print g_data

          for g_row in market:
               text = ''.join(g_row.findAll(text=True))
               g_data = text.strip()

               print g_data
```

My output:

```
Cleveland @ Cincinnati
102.93
Miami @ Buffalo
102.27
Green Bay @ Carolina
123.42
St Louis @ Minnesota
102.92
Washington @ New England
101.85
Tennessee @ New Orleans
185.93
Jacksonville @ New York Jets
189.21
Oakland @ Pittsburgh
102.51
Atlanta @ San Francisco
101.75
```

If you notice in this link [Click here](http://odds.aussportsbetting.com/betting?competitionid=15) you will see there is a lot more data that needs to be scraped however it stops. Can you help determine why?

Comment: I can't access that site, how does the data get loaded ? If the site uses an AJAX XMLHttpRequest the data is likely not there yet when you are scraping the site.

Comment: Have you tried using a different parser? `lxml`, or `html.parser`

Comment: Hi @Jkdc, did you want to write that as an answer. You were very correct, I tried to change the parser to html.parser and it works now. Thanks

Comment: Just to say, the code as is seemed to work fine for me on BS 4.3.2

Comment: @MartinEvans thanks for the input, im using beautifulsoup4==4.3.2 too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to change your parser.

The built in one, `html`, can pretty easily fail, use `html.parser` or `lxml` instead:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content,'html.parser')
```

See the [BeautifulSoup Docs](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser) for some more information about recommended parsers

Comment: `lxml` is the default if you have it installed.